# Jquery animate created element

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I made div, if i click on it, jquery makes bullet  and that element is animated. This is code:

```
$('.square').click(function() {

$('<div class="bullet"></div>').appendTo($('body')).animate({
    'margin-top': 554
  }, 2000, function() {
$(this).remove();
  });
});
```

It works properly when I'm not clicking second time on div before animation is done. If i do this, my second "bullet" starts animation from position of first.
How to fix that? Thank's for help :)

UPDATE##
Here's the jsfiddle with problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/2ghj1x45/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's because the elements all have a size because they aren't positioned absolutely so each bullet div you add has display block, so will get it's own line where it's height is bullet size + margin top , which increases as it's animated. try instead using position absolute so the bullet div doesn't affect the layout of any other div

[like so](https://jsfiddle.net/2ghj1x45/1/)

```
$(bullet).animate({ top: value });
```

Comment: you can use [position relative](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/) to define the coordinates to render absolutely positioned elements within it

Comment: Thank you, I understood problem now :) I thought this is something with js but, no - css and positioning elements. Thank's a lot!

Comment: no problem, a great tool for diagnosing weird css errors is to give everything a border, sometimes it will reveal to you the craziness that's going on behind the scenes

Answer (score 1):

Why not timeout the click function with a variable:

```
var animating = false;
$('.square').click(function() {

   if(!animating) {
      animating = true;
      setTimeout(function() {
          animating = false;
      }, 2000);

      $('<div class="bullet"></div>').appendTo($('body')).animate({
          'margin-top': 554
        }, 2000, function() {
           $(this).remove();
      });            
    }
});
```

### EDIT:

Updated [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ghj1x45/2/)